# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc] found for dependency:

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc, springmockito

I am trying to run test cases on my spring controllers. I get the following error.

> No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations

After reading several QA's on SO, I got my build.gradle right. But now Im stuck at this point. The other questions on SO related to this did not help identify an issue with the code below.

```
package test.controllers;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.mnox.database.pojo.wrapper.v2.VehicleMasterPojoWrapper.VehiclePurpose;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration({
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"
// ,
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml"
})
public class TestSpringOnLocalhost {

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Greetings from Spring Boot!")));
    }

    @Test
    public void test1CreateClient() {
        SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest vehicle = new SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest("123", "KA-02-1234", 12,
                VehiclePurpose.MAIN_VEHICLE.name(), "some alias");
        MvcResult mvcResult = null;
        try {
            MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/saveVehicleAjaxMethod")
                    .content(new Gson().toJson(vehicle).getBytes()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            mvcResult = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();
            mvcResult.getModelAndView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private class SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest {
        private String vehicleId;
        private String registrationNumber;
        private int seatingCapacity;
        private String vehicleType;
        private String vehicleAlias;

        public SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest(String vehicleId, String registrationNumber, int seatingCapacity,
                String vehicleType, String vehicleAlias) {
            super();
            this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
            this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
            this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
            this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
            this.vehicleAlias = vehicleAlias;
        }

        public String getVehicleId() {
            return vehicleId;
        }

        public void setVehicleId(String vehicleId) {
            this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
        }

        public String getRegistrationNumber() {
            return registrationNumber;
        }

        public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
            this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        }

        public int getSeatingCapacity() {
            return seatingCapacity;
        }

        public void setSeatingCapacity(int seatingCapacity) {
            this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
        }

        public String getVehicleType() {
            return vehicleType;
        }

        public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
            this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
        }

        public String getVehicleAlias() {
            return vehicleAlias;
        }

        public void setVehicleAlias(String vehicleAlias) {
            this.vehicleAlias = vehicleAlias;
        }
    }

}
```

My Spring controller code snippet for your reference

```
@Controller
public class SaveOrUpdateVehicleController extends AVehicleModel implements IViewOperation {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/saveVehicleAjaxMethod", "/modifyVehicleAjaxMethod" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String saveOrModifyVehicleAjaxMethod(
            @RequestParam(value = "vehicleId", required = false) String vehicleId,
            @RequestParam(value = "registrationNumber") String registrationNumber,
            @RequestParam(value = "seatingCapacity") int seatingCapacity,
            @RequestParam(value = "vehicleType") String vehicleType,
            @RequestParam(value = "vehicleAlias") String vehicleAlias, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
```

My build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.0-b07'
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli
compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl
compile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
// compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib
compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version: '2.4', classifier: 'jdk15'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client
compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-client', version: '1.15'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core
compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-core', version: '1.15'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'jsr311-api', version: '1.1.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna
compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '4.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform
compile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '4.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '1.5-20090211'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-tools
compile group: 'com.sun.istack', name: 'istack-commons-tools', version: '3.0.5'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.2.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/fluent-hc
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'fluent-hc', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gcm/gcm-server
compile group: 'com.google.gcm', name: 'gcm-server', version: '1.0.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-cache', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.0.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.0.39'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
compile name:'jsongpshelper'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/springframework/spring-mock
compile group: 'springframework', name: 'spring-mock', version: '1.2.6'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test
testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
//  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
//https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test', version: '4.3.5.RELEASE'


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test-mvc
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test-mvc', version: '1.0.0.M2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'
//testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
```

Edit
Tried one more variation based on https://www.luckyryan.com/2013/08/25/testing-spring-mvc-controllers/

Still no luck, stuck at the same point.

```
package test.controllers;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.mnox.database.pojo.wrapper.v2.VehicleMasterPojoWrapper.VehiclePurpose;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"})
public class ControllerTess {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void test1CreateClient() {
        SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest vehicle = new SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest("123", "KA-02-1234", 12,
                VehiclePurpose.MAIN_VEHICLE.name(), "some alias");
        MvcResult mvcResult = null;
        try {
            MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/saveVehicleAjaxMethod")
                    .content(new Gson().toJson(vehicle).getBytes()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request).andReturn();
            mvcResult.getModelAndView();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private class SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest {
        private String vehicleId;
        private String registrationNumber;
        private int seatingCapacity;
        private String vehicleType;
        private String vehicleAlias;

        public SaveOrUpdateVehicleAjaxRequest(String vehicleId, String registrationNumber, int seatingCapacity,
                String vehicleType, String vehicleAlias) {
            super();
            this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
            this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
            this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
            this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
            this.vehicleAlias = vehicleAlias;
        }

        public String getVehicleId() {
            return vehicleId;
        }

        public void setVehicleId(String vehicleId) {
            this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
        }

        public String getRegistrationNumber() {
            return registrationNumber;
        }

        public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
            this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        }

        public int getSeatingCapacity() {
            return seatingCapacity;
        }

        public void setSeatingCapacity(int seatingCapacity) {
            this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
        }

        public String getVehicleType() {
            return vehicleType;
        }

        public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
            this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
        }

        public String getVehicleAlias() {
            return vehicleAlias;
        }

        public void setVehicleAlias(String vehicleAlias) {
            this.vehicleAlias = vehicleAlias;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Modified

**FROM**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration({
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"
// ,
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml"
})
public class TestSpringOnLocalhost {
```

**TO**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration({
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml",
"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"
// ,
// "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml"
})
public class TestSpringOnLocalhost {
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'test.controllers.TestSpringOnLocalhost': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc test.controllers.TestSpringOnLocalhost.mvc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc test.controllers.TestSpringOnLocalhost.mvc; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
```

**EDIT 2, replace ContextConfiguration with ImportResource**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely rework your Gradle build script.

I recommend you start over by creating your `build.gradle` script using https://start.spring.io. That will configure compatible versions. For example, you should not be using Spring Framework 4.3.5 with Spring Boot 2.0.3, etc.

If done correctly, you find that you don't need to specify versions for most of your dependencies. In fact, you won't need to configure most of those dependencies explicitly. Spring Boot will do it for you.

Comment: TBH, I've never used XML configuration files with Spring Boot. What happens if you replace `@ContextConfiguration` with `@ImportResource`?

Comment: Another exception. Updated teh question

Comment: I just noticed that you have manually configured your dependencies which you should not be doing when using Spring Boot. See updated answer.

Comment: Your first suggestion seems to be pointless. The `webEnvironment` in `@SpringBootTest` defaults to `WebEnvironment.MOCK`. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#webEnvironment--). Your 2nd suggestion (about dependencies) is good.

Comment: Good catch, @naXa. I'll update my answer accordingly.